# Correct way of sending updates from Content Script to Popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that has `content_script`, `background_page` and `page_action` with popup.

So, popup has several controls, when user presses on control the popup should send a command to start work. Content script starts work, and should send an updates to popup.

The problem is that I'm not sure I implemented *updates* part properly.

Content script:

```
function notifyProgress(thing) {
  console.log('Notify progress');
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({req: 'Progress', thing: thing});
}
```

Background page:

```
var channel;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {

  if (port.name == 'service-channel') {
    channel = port;
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
      console.log('Background received event', msg);
      ...
    });
  }
});
...
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, callback) {
  console.log('On message in background', msg);
  if (msg.req == '...') {
    ...
  } else if (msg.req == 'Progress') {
    console.log('Got Progress for ' + sender.tab.id);
    channel.postMessage(msg);
  }
});
```

Popup:

```
var channel = chrome.extension.connect({name: 'service-channel'});
channel.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {

  if (message.req == '...') {
    ...
  } else if (message.req == 'Progress') {
    updateListener(message.req, {thing: message.thing}); // updates UI
  } else
    console.log('Ignoring', message);
});
```

Also I have worries about multiple working content scripts sending `Progress` events.

Is there a simpler or better way of doing this?

**Edit.**

What is best practices of implementing Popup updates from Content Script?

Comment: _"Basically I have worries about multiple working content scripts sending Progress events."_ You did not explain why that would be a problem. By the way, the popup is perfectly capable of receiving the original message itself (as long as it's open).

Comment: So, yes, I don't yet see what your problem here is (or what you think your problem is).

Comment: @Xan, so, I should remove the `channel` code and event handling from background page (background page is used only for these purposes). Is that correct?

Comment: It depends. If you don't care if the messages get lost while your popup is closed, then yes, this routing is unnecessary. If you _do_ care, your background page should keep a buffer of messages (in case `channel` is closed, for instance, do you check for that?). _But I still fail to see the problem here_, what is your question?

Comment: @Xan, I've updated the question. I didn't check is the `channel` opened. Thanks for that!

Comment: "Best practices" is terribly broad / primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Xan, yeah, but I'm newbie in writing chrome extensions, so I expect to see some recommendations for such kind of functionality, how-tos or something like this.

Comment: SO doesn't do recommendations.  It just doesn't work well with our format.  We're more the problem solving type.